# How to add columns dynamically in repeater control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add some dynamic columns to existing repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptdeliverable1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate> 
        <table border="1" width="100%" style="border-color: #99CCFF">       
           <tr>
            <th style="border-color: #99CCFF; text-decoration: underline; font-style: italic">
              Gate deliverable
            </th>
           </tr>
        </table> 
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <table border="1" width="100%" style="border-color: #99CCFF">      
           <tr> 
            <td id = "idDeliverable" style="border-color: #99CCFF">
              <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Deliverable") %>
            </td>
           </tr>
        </table>     
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

Please let me know how to do it. I am using datatable
`dt.Columns.Add("Deliverable", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))`

Comment: Switch to GridView Control. It's a `table` in HTML.